# Call a specific .net core mvc action periodically using AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, schedule

I have a running .net core mvc application on aws lambda. I would like to call an mvc action in every hour. As I found out one solution is to create a new lambda entry point and call that. But then I have to setup the application there again (context, DI etc). Other way could be to have a lambda which only purpose is to call the first application's endpoint, but this doesn't seem to be right.
Is there any way to make cloudwatch (or other aws resource) call the mvc action directly?

Answer (score 0):

For the people who seek answers:
The solution I chose is the following:

- Create a cloudwatch time trigger
- Create a SNS topic and call it with the created cloudwatch trigger
- Create a SNS subscription on that topic which calls an HTTP/S API

No code changes are needed.